# Calculate durance of running procedure (Oracle, PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have some PL/SQL block code doing update. Tables has a lot of data and I want to calculate how long it took.

```
declare
 cursor c1 is select * from my_Table;
 my_record.my_Table%rowtype;
 startDate DATE;
 endDate DATE;
begin
 SELECT SYSDATE into startDate FROM dual;
  open c1;
    loop fetch c1 into my_record; 
      exit when c1%notfound;      
       --some updates
      
    end loop;
   --commit;
  close c1;
  SELECT SYSDATE into endDate FROM dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(startDate - endDate);
end;
```

When I run I got strange value:

```
-,00001157407407407407407407407407407407407407
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mistake:** You are doing start time minus end time.

**Solution:** You need to reverse the order of your dates `enddate - startdate`.

Also, When you do `date1 - date2`, It will give you number of days between those two dates. You can convert it to required unit (days, hours, minutes, seconds) by multiplying it with correct number as follows:

You can update your `DBMS_OUTPUT` as follows:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ROUND((endDate - startDate),2)); --> Days
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ROUND((endDate - startDate) * 24, 2)); --> Hours
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ROUND((endDate - startDate) * 24 * 60, 2); --> minutes
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ROUND((endDate - startDate) * 24 * 60 * 60, 2)); --> seconds
```

**Another best way** to calculate the time taken by your SQL statements or PL/SQL block is to use SQL*Plus (also supported by various tools - SQL Developer, ..) command as follows:

```
SET TIMING ON
```

It will display the elapsed time of SQL statement or PL/SQL block.

Comment: I got this :PLS-00306: for DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ROUND(endDate - startDate),2);

Comment: SET TIMING ON -- it's working

Comment: There was missing bracket. Updated the answer for PLS-00306

Answer (score 1):

If you do `startDate - endDate` then you will get a negative number since `endDate` is greater than `startDate` and the result will be number representing the number of days.

Instead, you can use `(endDate - startDate) DAY TO SECOND` which will give a positive number and return an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type.

*Also, you do not need to use `SELECT` to set the start- and end-dates; do it in PL/SQL.*

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM my_Table;
  my_record my_Table%ROWTYPE;
  startDate DATE := SYSDATE;
  endDate   DATE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO my_record; 
    EXIT WHEN c1%notfound;      
    --some updates
      
  END LOOP;
  --commit;
  CLOSE c1;
  endDate := SYSDATE;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE((endDate - startDate) DAY TO SECOND);
END;
/
```

Which, depending on your sample data, may output:

> ```
> +000000000 00:00:08.000000000
> ```

If you want to know the fractional seconds then use `SYSTIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP` rather than `SYSDATE` and `DATE`:

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM my_Table;
  my_record my_Table%ROWTYPE;
  startDate TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  endDate   TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO my_record; 
    EXIT WHEN c1%notfound;      
    --some updates
      
  END LOOP;
  --commit;
  CLOSE c1;
  endDate := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE((endDate - startDate) DAY TO SECOND);
END;
/
```

Which, depending on your sample data, may output:

> ```
> +000000000 00:00:09.133979000
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6WWgwbyS)

Comment: generally should be min and second, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be [dbms_utility.get_time](https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTPLP/d_util.htm#TTPLP71385) which

> returns a measure of current time in hundredths of a second

In your procedure, that would be e.g.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_start number;
  3  begin
  4    l_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
  5    -- you'd do something smart here; I'm just waiting
  6    dbms_lock.sleep(3);
  7    -- divide by 100 because function - as said - measures hundredths of a second
  8    dbms_output.put_line('Elapsed time: ' || (dbms_utility.get_time - l_start) / 100 || ' seconds');
  9  end;
 10  /
Elapsed time: 3 seconds

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```